# Python3 folium : can't call ImageOverlay

Tags: python, python-3.x, overlay, folium

everyone,

I'm trying to overlay an image (IPython.display.Image), created from a numpy.array on a folium map, exactly like in [this example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/vincentropy/python_cartography_tutorial/blob/master/part2_custom_layers.ipynb), In[12], but with another data set. Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

`AttributeError: module "folium.plugins' has no attribute "ImageOverlay"`

Probably due to the fact that ImageOverlay disappeared between the version of folium.plugins 0.5.0 and 0.6.0 (indeed it no longer appears in the documentation).

Is there any other way to do this overlay? Otherwise, is there a way to force use previous versions of folium.plugins to be able to call the old function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT** :
In case someone else encounters this problem in the future: after trying to work around this problem for several hours, I finally found the code for this old folium.plugins function on Github: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/raster_layers.py.

Answer (score 4):

use "folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay" instead of "folium.plugins.ImageOverlay"

Comment: import as ```from folium.raster_layers import ImageOverlay```